# Is it possible to use AVAudioRecorder without silencing playback?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avaudiorecorder

i'm using AVAudioRecorder to detect blows into the mic of the iPhone. But when i "record", the iPhone silences background music. Is there a way to avoid this?

I've tried to set the audio session category to ambient:

```
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:&error];
```

But then recording isn't allowed anymore.

Also the mixwithothers property is not allowed to be set if you use the record category

```
UInt32 allowMixing = true;
propertySetError = AudioSessionSetProperty(
                        kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, 
                        sizeof(allowMixing), 
                        &allowMixing
                        );
```